# How to route to host in docker container during 'docker build'

Tags: routes, docker, containers, host

**TL;DR**
My Dockerfile has a `RUN` step that executes a shell script that downloads a build from a build server. I'd like this build server to be on my docker host for quick transfer. If possible, how can I get the container spun up for the `docker build` command to route to my host (without going out to the Internet, of course)?

**Details**
I have a fairly large code repository (>500MB) that I want to stage and run in a docker container. Because the repo is so large, staging the code with an `ADD` directive not only takes a great deal of time, but also takes up way more space in my docker containers than I'd like (I build frequently enough that space constraints are a problem). My solution to this problem is to:

- pull from a base image that already has my code repo staged
- make use of a `RUN` step that executes a shell script that downloads the latest code as a tarball, untars it, and rsyncs the contents to the already staged repo

My Dockerfile looks something like this:

```
FROM my.image.server.com/base/image:latest

ADD build.sh /tmp/build.sh
RUN cd /tmp && bash ./build.sh && rm -f build.sh
```

And build.sh looks something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Start from a clean state
rm -rf ./tmp/repo
mkdir -p ./tmp/repo

# Download my tar'd repo
wget http://my.build.server.com/repo.tar
wget http://my.build.server.com/repo.tar.sha1
shasum -C repo.tar.sha1
tar -xf repo -C ./tmp/repo

# Stage changed code; /opt/repo is where the code lives in my base image
rsync -a --delete ./tmp/repo /opt/repo

# Clean up so my image is as small as possible
rm -rf repo.tar*
rm -rf ./tmp/website
```

This works great for keeping my images small, and speeds the `docker build` step as well. However, I'd like to make things faster by downloading the tarball locally (i.e from a file server running on my docker host). Unfortunately, the docker container spun up for the `docker build` step is unable to route to my host machine.

I know that it is possible to forward ports from host to container and bridge host to container when spinning up containers (i.e. `docker run`), but haven't been able to find any documentation on how to route from docker container to host during `docker build`. Is this possible? If so, how can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a pretty way to access the host during build, but it is accessible: use `ifconfig` or similar to see the IP addresses for your host.

For example, my `en0` currently has address `10.0.1.17` (a private subnet). If your file server is listening on that interface, then your build.sh could say

```
wget http://10.0.1.17/repo.tar
```

The problem, of course, is that you can't give this Dockerfile to someone else unless you want them to talk to *your* fileserver, and if you're on DHCP your IP will change. You could do some other things to kludge around this, like adding your own network interface.

Comment: Awesome. I didn't realize the container would route to any of the interfaces on the host. Creating a virtual interface on the host for this purpose works like a charm. For what it's worth, I'm not concerned about the portability of the Dockerfile, as it will live behind and be controlled by an API whose endpoints devs can post to in order create builds and deployments.

Comment: If you want to keep your Dockerfile portable in the future, you can use multiple `COPY` commands to copy the most frequently changing files/directories at the end of the Dockerfile. That way, building the image won't copy all the files every time. See the [Dockerfile Best Practices](https://docs.docker.com/articles/dockerfile_best-practices/#add-or-copy)